# Use String.Join to Build Linq to SQL ContainsTable Search Condition

Tags: string, linq-to-sql

I'm using a SQL Server UDF to allow me to use CONTAINSTABLE in Linq to SQL.

I'm using a string array and regular expressions to split the user's search string into recognizable words and then reassembling the string array into a search condition string that conforms to CONTAINSTABLE syntax.

I'd like to enable the user to be able to surround phrases in quotes. In other words, if the user enters 'yellow "blue green"' the search condition should be 'yellow OR "blue green"' What would be the best way to handle this given the following code.

```
IEnumerable<string> keywords = Regex
    .Matches(search, @"(?<match>\w+)|\""(?<match>[\w\s]*)""")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups["match"].Value)
    .ToList();

string searchCondition = "";
searchCondition = String.Join(" OR ", keywords);

List = from t1 in List
    join fts in _dc.udfSearchContent(searchCondition)
    on t1.ContentID equals fts.ContentID
    select t1;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.Select(x => @"""" + x + @"""")` does the trick.

```
IEnumerable<string> keywords = Regex
    .Matches(search, @"(?<match>\w+)|\""(?<match>[\w\s]*)""")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups["match"].Value)
    .ToList();

string searchCondition = "";
searchCondition = String.Join(" OR ", keywords.Select(x => @"""" + x + @""""));

List = from t1 in List
    join fts in _dc.udfSearchContent(searchCondition)
    on t1.ContentID equals fts.ContentID
    select t1;
```